# Fixing the URL with Coldfusion regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need to edit some URL data, but i am facing some issue, the url is coming as:

```
<cfset myurl = "http:/example.com/0.asp?rpttype=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&companyQ=195&companyQ=105&companyQ=136&companyQ=126&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043stateQ=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1">

<cfset reURL = queryStringDeleteVar("companyQ",myurl)>
<cfset reURL = queryStringDeleteVar("productQ",reURL)>
<cfset reURL = reURL & "&companyQ=">
<cfset listData = ''>
<cfloop list="#getCompanyID#" index="k">
    <cfset listData = ListChangeDelims(ListPrepend(listData,"%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=" & k),'',',')>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#reURL##listData#" label="URL Rewritten">
```

rewriting as:

```
http://example.com/0.asp?rpttype=298&stateQ=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1&companyQ=%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=186%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=176%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=150%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=148
```

but it needs to be like this

```
http://example.com/0.asp?rpttype=298&stateQ=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1&companyQ=186%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=176%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=150%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=148
```

i am missing something,

please guide

this

**companyQ=%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=186**

needs to like this for the first one only

**companyQ=186**

***only the first one, remaining will stay as it is:***

the value *186 is dynamic*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should just help you.

```
<cfset myurl = "http:/example.com/0.asp?rpttype=298&companyQ=148&companyQ=150&companyQ=176&companyQ=186&companyQ=195&companyQ=105&companyQ=136&companyQ=126&productQ=1072&productQ=1042&productQ=1043stateQ=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1">
<cfset reURL = queryStringDeleteVar("companyQ",myurl)>
<cfset reURL = queryStringDeleteVar("productQ",reURL)>
<cfset reURL = reURL & "&companyQ=#listFirst(getCompanyID)#">
<cfset getCompanyID = listDeleteAt(getCompanyID,1)>
<cfset listData = ''>
<cfloop list="#getCompanyID#" index="k">
    <cfset listData =ListPrepend(listData,"%27+or+q2.comp+%3D%27=" & k)>
</cfloop>
<cfset listData = listChangeDelims(listData,"") />
<cfdump var="#reURL##listData#" label="URL Rewritten">
```